# In Rust, what is the purpose of a mod.rs file?

Tags: module, rust

In some Rust projects I've seen (i.e [pczarn/rustboot](https://github.com/pczarn/rustboot)), I've seen `mod.rs` files in directories for whatever reason. I've not been able to find documentation about this, and I've seen it in many other Rust projects.
What is the purpose of a mod.rs file, and when should I use it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Imagine the following directory structure:

```
code/
  `- main.rs
   - something/
     `- mod.rs
```

If in `main.rs` you do `mod something;`, then it'll look in the `something/mod.rs` file to use as the contents of the module declaration for `something`.

The alternative to this is to have a `something.rs` file in the `code/` directory.

So to recap, when you write an empty module declaration such as `mod something;`, it looks either in:

- a file called `something.rs` in the same directory
- a file called `mod.rs` in a folder called `something` in the same directory

It then uses the contents of either of those files to use as the contents of the module declaration.

Comment: Could I use any filename instead of `mod.rs`, or is that a builtin.

Comment: You can specify any path you want using the `#[path = "thefile.rs"]` attribute, but it's generally discouraged since the convention is what I specified in my answer. [See the reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#modules).

Comment: 1. What happens when both the files are present? `something.rs` and `something/mod.rs`? 2. Isn't that weird that every file's default name is expected to be `mod.rs`, making search a horrible experience?

Comment: In Rust 2018, mod.rs is not needed [https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html)

Answer (score 82):

Modules are important to understand, but I find most documentations often leave you scratching your head on that matter.

#### Coming from **Python** or **Javascript**?

Roughly, `mod.rs` is kind of like `__init__.py` in python or `index.js` in javascript.
But only kind of. This is a bit more complicated in Rust.

#### Rust is different

Folders are not immediately ready to use as modules in Rust.

You have to add a file named `mod.rs` in a folder to expose a new module named like that folder.
The code in `mod.rs` is the content of that module.
All other files in the folder may in turn be exposed as submodules (more on that below).

#### Wait, there is another way

Instead of adding a `mod.rs` file in the folder, you may add a file named `<folder_name>.rs` at the same level as the folder.

As noted by MarkusToman in the comments, this is the preferred way since rustc 1.30.

From the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#module-source-filenames):

> Note: Previous to rustc 1.30, using mod.rs files was the way to load
> a module with nested children. It is encouraged to use the new
> naming convention as it is more consistent, and avoids having many
> files named mod.rs within a project.

#### Complete example

```
src
    utils
        bar.rs
        foo.rs
    main.rs
```

At this point, the compiler doesn't know about `src/utils/foo.rs` and `src/utils/bar.rs`.

First, you must expose `src/utils/`. As seen above, you have 2 options:

- add the file: `src/utils/mod.rs`
- add the file `src/utils.rs` (named exactly like the folder, without the extension)

Now, relative to the src folder (aka the crate level), a module named `utils` is available.

Second, you must expose the files `src/utils/foo.rs` and `src/utils/bar.rs`.

To do that, the `utils` module must declare 2 new submodules named after these files.
So the content of `src/utils/mod.rs` (or `src/utils.rs`) should be:

```rs
pub mod bar;
pub mod foo;
```

Now whatever is public in those 2 files is available in other modules!

And you may write the following in `src/main.rs`:

```rs
mod utils;
use utils::{foo, bar};
```

#### Resulting file structure

**Option 1 • `mod.rs`** (the old way):

```
src
    utils
        bar.rs
        foo.rs
        mod.rs
    main.rs
```

**Option 2 • `<folder_name>.rs`** (the preferred way):

```
src
    utils
        bar.rs
        foo.rs
    utils.rs
    main.rs
```

---

#### More advanced details on how modules work

> This remains a surface explanation, your next destination is the official documentation ‍

There is a third way to declare modules (core language):

```rs
mod utils {
  // module code goes here. That's right, inside of the file.
}
```

But it is also possible to just write `mod utils;`.
In that case, as seen above, Rust knows to search for either of `src/utils.rs` or `src/utils/mod.rs`.

See, when you try to use a module in a file (in `src/main.rs` for example),
you may reference it in the following ways:

- from inside: `src/main.rs`

  - `mod module { ... }`
- from nested modules inside: `src/main.rs`

  - `mod module { pub mod sub_module { ... } }`
- from sybling files: `src/*.rs`
- from `mod.rs` files in sybling folders: `src/*/mod.rs`
- (and infinite reccursive combinations of the above)

**A file or a folder containing `mod.rs` does not become a module.**
Rather, the Rust language lets you organize modules (a language feature) with a file hierarchy.

What makes it really interesting is that you are free to mix all approaches together.

For example, you may think you can't directly reference `src/utils/foo.rs` from `main.rs`.
But you can:

```rs
// src/main.rs
mod utils {
  pub mod foo;
}
```

**Important notes**:

- modules declared in files will always take precedence (because you in fact never need to search the file hierarchy)
- you can't use the other 2 approaches to reference the same module

For example, having both `src/utils.rs` and `src/utils/mod.rs` will raise the following error at compile time:

```rs
error[E0761]: file for module `utils` found at both "src/utils.rs" and "src/utils/mod.rs"
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | mod utils;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: delete or rename one of them to remove the ambiguity
```

Let's wrap up. Modules are exposed to the compiler:

- from top to bottom
- by reference only
  (That's why you don't have intellisense until your modules are "imported")
- starting from an entry point
  (which is `src/main.rs` or `src/lib.rs` by default.
  But it may be anything that you configure in `Cargo.toml`.
  This has little to do with this question however)

With our previous example we get in order:

1. `src/main.rs` -> `crate`

   Because the `crate` module contains `mod utils;` we next get:
2. `src/utils.rs` OR `src/utils/mod.rs` -> `crate::utils`

   Because the `utils` module contains `mod foo;` we next get:
3. `src/utils/foo.rs` -> `crate::utils::foo`

Comment: Thanks, the Rust book is really weak in this regards. When you expose foo and bar, do you then do use utils::foo or just use foo? I would suspect the latter?

Comment: I just found in https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#module-source-filenames that "Note: Previous to rustc 1.30, using mod.rs files was the way to load a module with nested children. It is encouraged to use the new naming convention as it is more consistent, and avoids having many files named mod.rs within a project."

Comment: @MarkusToman To use foo and bar in a file (main.rs for example), you need to bring the module in scope with `mod utils;` and then `use utils::{foo, bar};`

Comment: What if I don't want a nested directory but want to put the other files at the same level as `main.rs`?

Comment: One problem with your explanation. Folders do become modules by having a mod.rs in them so you don't need to export a module named like the folder in mod.rs, just the submodules. The folder automatically becomes a module. mod.rs is a way to avoid creating a folder + a file with the same name (+.rs) to have nested modules.

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @RomainVincent, if you're not going to try to explain yourself, I cannot help.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar simply put foo.rs and bar.rs directly in src. They will be accessible the same way utils.rs is. And the 3 of them will be modules, they actually don't require to have submodules. If you however want foo and bar to be submodules of utils while being directly in src, then you can't... Your best bet is to `mod foo {<body>}` and `mod bar {<body>}` in utils.rs

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic answer! After scratching my head with the rust book and other bad examples, this was so clean and straightforward. Coming from another language I found it extremely difficult to properly organise my code in folders in rust, before I met this answer. Most examples are lacking any real form of nesting, probably to avoid scaring away newcomers.

Comment: @TalnaciSergiuVlad My pleasure. Modules are always a pain, and just like you, I felt a bit let down by all the official docs and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Each `rs` file, except lib.rs and main.rs, which always match the `crate` module, gets its own module.

There is only one way to declare a module:

```rust
/* pub */ mod sub_module1;
```

A module cannot be declare outside the root/crate module tree (i.e., going up the module tree, a submodule must always have a parent that is declared directly in `lib.rs` or `main.rs`, so the first program submodule must always be declared there — a tree data structure if it isn't already obvious enough).

There are 2 ways to nest a module inside the module where it is declared:

- in `<module_where_it_is_declared>/<module_name.rs>`
- in `<module_where_it_is_declared>/module_name/mod.rs`

If `module_where_it_is_declared` is the crate module, then this corresponding subfolder is not needed (disappears from the scheme above).

Here is an example, valid for both lib and binary crates:

```
src
|---lib.rs ( contains: pub mod b2; )
|---b2.rs ( contains: pub mod bb2; )
|---b2
|   |---bb2.rs
.   .
```

Alternatively:

```
src
|---lib.rs ( contains: pub mod b2; )
|---b2
|   |---mod.rs ( contains: pub mod bb2; )
|   |---bb2.rs
.   .
```

You can see that you can mix and match (b2 uses `mod.rs` way, bb2 uses the "file"-way).

Here's a way to only use the file pattern that is also valid:

```
src
|---lib.rs ( contains: pub mod b2; )
|---b2.rs ( contains: pub mod bb2; )
|---b2
|   |---bb2.rs (contains: pub mod bbb2; )
|   |---bbb2.rs (contains: pub mod bbbb2; )
|   |---bbb2
|   |   |---bbbb2.rs
.   .   .
```

I guess it depends on you how you want to nest modules.

I like the `mod.rs` syntax for modules that just export other submodules and don't have any other (or very little) code in them, although you can put whatever you want in `mod.rs`.

I use `mod.rs` similar to the barrel pattern from JS/TS world, to rollup several submodules into a single parent module.

Also don't forget modules can be defined (not only declared) inline by adding a scope block:

```rs
pub mod my_submodule {
    // ...
}
```